# Why are there two lines showing in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I do not understand why matplotlib is creating another line?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xy1 = []
x1 = 0


while x1 < 10:
    x1 = x1 + 1
    y1 = x1**2 
    xy1.append([x1,y1])


plt.plot(xy1)
print(xy1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot), you can see that `plt.plot` can take in multiple plots:

```
If x and/or y is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns will be plotted.
```

Your data looks like:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9], [4, 16], [5, 25], [6, 36], [7, 49], [8, 64], [9, 81], [10, 100]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Hooked says, its because `xy1` is 2-dimensional, and `plot` will plot 2-dimensional arrays as two columns, not an x and a y column.

Currently, your list looks like:

```
In [14]: xy1
Out[14]: 
[[1, 1],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 9],
 [4, 16],
 [5, 25],
 [6, 36],
 [7, 49],
 [8, 64],
 [9, 81],
 [10, 100]]
```

To plot `x` against `y`, you need to unpack it into two lists. You can use `zip` and the `*` operator to do this:

```
In [25]: xy2=zip(*xy1)

In [26]: xy2
Out[26]: [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), (1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)]
```

Which you can then plot by unpacking again with the `*` operator:

```
In [28]: plt.plot(*xy2)
Out[28]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10808c090>]

In [29]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you turn `xy1` into `numpy.array`, you can use the `transpose` function:

```
In [48]: import numpy as np

In [49]: xy3=np.array(xy1)

In [50]: xy3
Out[50]: 
array([[  1,   1],
       [  2,   4],
       [  3,   9],
       [  4,  16],
       [  5,  25],
       [  6,  36],
       [  7,  49],
       [  8,  64],
       [  9,  81],
       [ 10, 100]])

In [51]: plt.plot(*xy3.transpose())
```